# functions.php causing white pages in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

For some reason, when I edit my functions.php, various pages turn white. For exmaple, with this code:

```
    <?php
    /* Add a custom field to the field editor (See editor screenshot) */
    add_action("gform_field_standard_settings", "my_standard_settings", 10, 2);
    function my_standard_settings($position, $form_id){
        // Create settings on position 25 (right after Field Label)
        if($position == 25){
?>
            <li class="admin_label_setting field_setting" style="display: list-item; ">
                <label for="field_placeholder">Placeholder Text
                    <!-- Tooltip to help users understand what this field does -->
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="tooltip tooltip_form_field_placeholder" tooltip="&lt;h6&gt;Placeholder&lt;/h6&gt;Enter the placeholder/default text for this field.">(?)</a>
                </label>
                <input type="text" id="field_placeholder" class="fieldwidth-3" size="35" onkeyup="SetFieldProperty('placeholder', this.value);">
            </li>
<?php
        }
    }
    /* Now we execute some javascript technicalitites for the field to load correctly */
    add_action("gform_editor_js", "my_gform_editor_js");
    function my_gform_editor_js(){
?>
        <script>
            //binding to the load field settings event to initialize the checkbox
            $(document).bind("gform_load_field_settings", function(event, field, form){
                $("#field_placeholder").val(field["placeholder"]);
            });
        </script>

<?php
    }
    /* We use jQuery to read the placeholder value and inject it to its field */
    add_action('gform_enqueue_scripts',"my_gform_enqueue_scripts", 10, 2);
    function my_gform_enqueue_scripts($form, $is_ajax=false){
?>
        <script>
            jQuery(function(){
                <?php
                    /* Go through each one of the form fields */
                    foreach($form['fields'] as $i=>$field){
                        /* Check if the field has an assigned placeholder */
                        if(isset($field['placeholder']) && !empty($field['placeholder'])){
                            /* If a placeholder text exists, inject it as a new property to the field using jQuery */
                ?>
                jQuery('#input_<?php echo $form['id']?>_<?php echo $field['id']?>').attr('placeholder','<?php echo $field['placeholder']?>');
                <?php
                        }
                    }
                ?>
            });
        </script>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Updating pages leaves me at a blank white page (at url: /wp-admin/post.php). Another piece of code I was trying to use, from this tutorial:

http://www.doitwithwp.com/pre-populate-fields-using-gravity-forms/

Causes a blank, white pages at the log in page. I'm running the latest version of WordPress. Any ideas why this would be happening?

Comment: It's likely you do not have error reporting on and the whitespace before the first <?php tag is causing a headers already sent error. Remove the empty space so <?php is the first thing in the file without any leading spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing any whitespace before the start PHP tag. Sometimes this causes a great trouble. Generally make sure it does not echo anything, as this file ONLY contains functions for later use and serves no content.

Comment: removing all unnecessary white space did it. That's strange.

Comment: Not strange, sometimes, systems rely on sending some headers just before the content is generated, so if you send any string, then headers would fail and may crash the rest of the code...

Comment: I still think that's strange, you'd think it could be smart enough to adapt to it. Really the only "coding" languages I use regularly are JavaScript/jQuery/HTML/CSS. In those languages, white space doesn't matter, and I still don't really understand why it matters with PHP.

Comment: in those langs, you have no headers sent. You only modify and manage the document already created in the browser, while in PHP, you CREATE this doc and send headers, needed for the browser, that are not part of the document.